# execCommand not working properly in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

The problem is with the execCommand, it is not being executed in IE even in IE10 properly .
For instance,
When I click bold and keeps on typing, in IE it is not making the letters bold, I have to select the text and click bold in order to make it bold. In all other browsers its will make the letters bold when I click bold button and keeps on typing.

Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q65Qt/

Here is the code

```
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
    oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
    sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
    if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
        setDocMode(true);
    }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
    if (validateMode()) {
        document.execCommand(sCmd, false, null);
        oDoc.focus();
    }
}

function validateMode() {
    if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
        return true;
    }
    alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
    return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
    var oContent;
    if (bToSource) {
        oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
        oDoc.innerHTML = "";
        var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
        oDoc.contentEditable = false;
        oPre.id = "sourceText";
        oPre.contentEditable = true;
        oPre.appendChild(oContent);
        oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    } else {
        if (document.all) {
            oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
        } else {
            oContent = document.createRange();
            oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
            oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
        }
        oDoc.contentEditable = true;
    }
    oDoc.focus();
}
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q65Qt/

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `document.execCommand()`. Instead, the issue seems to be that the editable element loses focus when a button is clicked and as a result loses the boldness when the focus is restored.

The simplest solution is to prevent the button click stealing the focus. You can do this by using the `mousedown` event instead of the `click` event and preventing the browser's default behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q65Qt/1/

Alternatively, you could make the buttons unselectable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527098/96100, for example.